# Microsoft Azure Web Chat, trigger mic from other function

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, botframework, voice-recognition

I have used Microsoft Bot Framework to create a bot for the client side. i.e. called WebChat. I have also added Speech SpeechRecognizer. However, I am trying to trigger a mic when a phrase is recited.

I couldn't find a function in Microsoft that does this. So I added my own speech recognizer that is called every second and once the phrase is called I want to call the mic function from the Cognitive Services.

How Can I achieve this?

I have got the speech recognizer from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#customizing-web-chat)

And the one I have written to identify a phrase is this:

```
function startDictation() {

            if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

                var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

                recognition.continuous = false;
                recognition.interimResults = false;

                recognition.lang = "en-US";
                recognition.start();

                recognition.onresult = function (e) {
                    var foundText = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                    console.log(foundText);
                    if (foundText == "hello hello") {
                        console.log("found text");
                        //call cognitive service mic function
                        recognition.stop();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("text not found");
                        recognition.stop();
                        startDictation();
                    }
                };

                recognition.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.log("found error", e);
                    recognition.stop();
                }

            }
        }
```

Do let me know if any information is missing or miss-leading.

For more:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to leverage `startRecognizing()` function in `SpeechRecognizer` class at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L72 to trigger the recognize functionality. However, I found that only if I have click the mic item, then I could use `startRecognizing()` function to recognize the voice.

There is a trick workaround you can try to use at present:

I inspected the mic item, and try to triiger its `click` event in js, which worked exactly to recognize my speech.

[image]

You can try to use following js code snippet with jQuery:

```
$('.wc-mic').trigger("click")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked. however, I have another question. that is how can I press the send 'button' from jquery. It will be good if you can help me.

Comment: similar trick method, try `$('.wc-send').trigger("click")` after you have triggerred the `mic` event and the mic icon been replaced by a paper plane icon.

Comment: Thanks. but doesnt seem to work. because it looks like the button is inactive, and hence the "click" cannot be triggered.